# Object can't access all the data from another object, but only what I've specified. How to fix?

Tags: java, object

Before anything, I would like to say that I am entirely new to Java, I only started understanding the very basics of it a few days ago.

I have a problem with objects here and I will show you what I mean.

This is the code for one of the functions, which is supposed to show me the stock item that has the most frequency:

```
InternalComponent ic = new InternalComponent("Intel", 4, 35.0, 3200.00);

public void FindMostFrequency()
{
    double temp = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i< Stock.size(); i++)
       if (ic.frequency > temp)
           temp = ic.frequency;
    System.out.println("The stock with most frequency is: " + temp );
}
```

The problem is that it uses the information only from a specific object and I would like to make it so it uses it from all objects.

Once again, I would like to point out that, what I've done here, is most likely wrong. Please point out any mistakes if possible, I really appreciate any help I can get.

This is the code for the InternalComponent class:

```
package com.company;

public class InternalComponent extends Stock {
    protected double frequency;

    public InternalComponent(String manufacturer, int count, double price,double frequency) {
        super(manufacturer, count, price);
        this.frequency = frequency;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "InternalComponent{" +
                "frequency=" + frequency +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: When you do `Stock.size()`, what is `Stock` and why are you doing nothing with it? I assume it's a collection of elements of type `Stock` or a subtype thereof, since you call `size()` on it, but if that's the case you're not doing anything with the elements it contains.

Comment: The problem is that I have two stocks, but it only shows the frequency of one because of the way I have made the object above the FindMostFrequency() function. It only uses the values for one of the stock items, can I somehow make it so it uses all of the stock added. Sorry if I did not explain it well.

Comment: Where are you adding those stocks? Please post all of the relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use something like this ... you need a 2nd variable to capture the Stock, and a method to get the Stocks (getStocks()):

```
public void FindMostFrequency()
{
    double temp = 0;
    Stock mostFrequentStock = null;
    for (Stock aStock : getStocks()) {
       var frequency = aStock.frequency
       if (temp < frequency) {
           temp = frequency;
           mostFrequentStock = aStock
       }
    }
    System.out.println("The stock with most frequency is: " + mostFrequentStock);
}
```

It would also be better to access the variable using a getter instead of directly, ie getFrequency()

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks almost correct but it doesn't seem like you define the body of the for loop with curly braces.  As other posters have mentioned using a foreach loop is usually preferred in cases like this.

Looping through each of the elements and simply invoking a getFrequency() method would be better. Then compare that with your current maxFrequency value. It's usually good practice to make the instance variables of a class private and have them only accessible through getters and setters.